# Laravel delete 1 key in paket but no feedback and changes

Tags: laravel, soft-delete

I have 2 models :

```
    class Penghuni extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        'nama_penghuni', 'email', 'phone', 'tower',
        'no_unit'
    ];

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function penghunis() {

        return $this->hasMany(Penghuni::class);
    }
}
```

and

```
class Packet extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'tanggal_masuk', 'tanggal_keluar', 'penerima', 'email', 'phone', 'no_unit', 'penghuni_id'
    ];

    public function penghuni() {
        
        return $this->belongsTo(Penghuni::class);
    }
}
```

when I want to do softdelete there is no update at deleted_at column value, but redirected as my controller is success. here is my controller:

```
public function destroy(Packet $packet)
    {
        $packet->delete();

        session()->flash('success', 'Delete Packet Berhasil');

        return redirect(route('paket.index'));
    }
```

there is no change when I did the delete, my button is:

```
<a href="javascript:$('#delete_paket{{ $paket->id }}').submit();" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Anda yakin ingin menghapus data paket {{ $paket->name }}?');">Delete</a>
                                                <form action="{{ route('paket.destroy', $paket->id) }}" method="POST" id="delete_paket{{ $paket->id }}">
                                                    @csrf
                                                    @method('DELETE')
                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" hidden>Delete</button>
                                                </form>
```

Comment: try to check value of `$packet` on you destroy method using `dd($packet)`

Comment: can you provide your route definition for this ... if you used Resource routing then the route parameter would be named `paket` not `packet`

Comment: it return this
App\Packet {#1186 ▼
  #fillable: array:8 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: array:1 [▶]
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #forceDeleting: false
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `$packet` to your route name in singular form, but as you used not english language just use your route name:

```
public function destroy(Packet $paket)
```

another way don't use model in method arg:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $packet = Packet::find($id)
        $packet->delete();

        session()->flash('success', 'Delete Packet Berhasil');

        return redirect(route('paket.index'));
    }
```

Comment: thank you, I use another way method you provide

Answer (score 1):

Your route parameter is problably `paket` not `packet`. Change your method signature so the parameter name matches the route parameter name:

```
public function destroy(Packet $paket)
```

If this doesn't match then Laravel just thinks you want dependency injection not route model binding. So you currently are getting a new model instance (non existing model instance) instead of your model binding (existing model instance).

You can run `php artisan route:list` to see what the route parameter is named.